# SonarQube Eclipse plugin : change default server configuration

Tags: sonarqube

I try to change the default SonarQube server value in SonarQube Eclipse plugin (v3.2)...

Using the `pluginCustomization` process (argument `-pluginCustomization myPrefs.ini` in *eclipse.ini* file), I add the same value as result of eclipse preferences export :

```
    # SonarQube default configuration server
    org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core/servers/http\:\\2f\\2fsonar.mycompany.org/auth=true
```

But after workspace creation, the default value is always `http://localhost:9000`

This is a bug ? or there is a best common way to do that ?

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow. FYI: You can put stuff like `pluginCustomization` and `http://localhost:9000` between backticks if you'd like it to show up as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24/09/2015 Update : **Fixed** with SonarQube Eclipse plugin v3.5 (see [SONARCLIPS-428](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCLIPS-428)).

---

It is not the answer but a trick ... if you consider :

- Having your own plugin with some [IStartup](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IStartup.html&ei=aWwCUrqxLcy2hAe79oCwCQ&usg=AFQjCNGamK-Sg-bJfDw-5obrv8p7q3nfCw&sig2=xEW7Z7fTRAECdaewlRMpqQ&bvm=bv.50310824,d.Yms&cad=rja) process in the Eclipse distribution
- You are using a proxy with the same credentials as SonarQube

This code could help you in an `earlyStartup()` method :

```
// Plugin dependencies : org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core, org.eclipse.core.net

// Write a process to do this code once (IEclipsePreferences use)
// ...

String userName = null;
String password = null;

// Get first login/password defined in eclipse proxy configuration
BundleContext bc = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getBundleContext();
ServiceReference<?> serviceReference = bc.getServiceReference(IProxyService.class.getName());
IProxyService proxyService = (IProxyService) bc.getService(serviceReference);
if (proxyService.getProxyData() != null) {
    for (IProxyData pd : proxyService.getProxyData()) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(pd.getUserId()) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(pd.getPassword())) {
            userName = pd.getUserId();
            password = pd.getPassword();
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Configure SonarQube with url and proxy user/password if exist
SonarCorePlugin.getServersManager().addServer("http://sonarqube.mycompany.com", userName, password);

// Store process done in preferences
// ...
```

Comment: Patch / Pull request submited on sonar-eclipse : [github link](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-eclipse/pull/6)